# Retrofit neither onResponse() nor onFailure() methods getting called

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I have an API call in my MainActivity that looks like the following:

```
private void refreshImageIds() {
    Retrofit retrofit = Api.getRestAdapter();
    FlickrServiceInterface flickrService = retrofit.create(FlickrServiceInterface.class);
    Call<PhotosList> call = flickrService.getPhotos(API_KEY, FORMAT, "1");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotosList>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PhotosList> call, Response<PhotosList> response) {
            photosList = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PhotosList> call, Throwable t) {
            // TODO: Clean up
            Log.d("TEMP_TAG", "Call failed");
        }
    });
}
```

So I'm calling this `refreshImageIds()` method from `onCreate()` to pull some data from the web. My issue is that my `photosList` object never gets set. This is a class-level variable.

When I step through with the debugger I can see it is getting to `enqueue()` and then skipping right over it. Any ideas what the issue is? My POJOs seem to all be set up correctly, and I've used an OkHttp logger to look at the URL it is calling, and that seems fine. When I type the URL into my browser I see the expected JSON.

Because of this `photosList` is never getting set and remains a null, causing a nullpointerexception later on in my app.

My other relevant classes are below.

Api.java:

```
public class Api {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getRestAdapter(){

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

FlickrServiceInterface.java:

```
public interface FlickrServiceInterface {

    @GET("?method=flickr.photos.getSizes")
    Call<PhotoSizes> getPhotoSizes(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("format") String format, @Query("nojsoncallback") String jsonCallback, @Query("photo_id") String photoId);

    @GET("?method=flickr.photos.getRecent")
    Call<PhotosList> getPhotos(@Query("api_key") String apiKey, @Query("format") String format, @Query("nojsoncallback") String jsonCallback);
}
```

Comment: That's an asynchronous operation. You should not expect your debugger to to go from the `enqueue()` call directly to `onResponse()`. Do not try to use `photosList` until `onResponse()` is called.

Comment: Ok right, so then is my network call just never getting through? How can I find out if the call is ever getting made?

Comment: Temporarily remove or comment out whatever is using `photosList` currently, and causing the crash. Then put a break point, or a log print, or a `Toast`, etc. in `onResponse()`, and try again.

Comment: Ok awesome, that works. But how can I now use that `photosList` object in the rest of my code?

Comment: Don't do anything with it until `onResponse()` is called. That is, call whatever code is currently crashing _from_ `onResponse()`, instead of right after your `refreshImageIds()` call.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. Though I think I've kind of messed up my design because I immediately need to make another API call using the imageIds that are contained in my `photosList`

Comment: Why can't you just make that API call from `onResponse()`? I mean, you can't use them until you get them, anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. yeah you're right. I just felt kinda funny doing it, but it's working. I'll change things around a bit so the design is a bit better. Thanks for your help. Sorry for all the double posting, just on a time constraint and was really stuck.